# Sorry: Another TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I know this has been asked a million times, I have looked at the other answers, but for some reason I just don't get it. Sorry for the repeat. I've been working on this for DAYS

TLDR: How do I correctly pass an array of objects into state?

I have created a React Hook, which is a button, that has an OnClick that fires off an action and reducer.

The reducer logic takes an array taken from `state`, that splits it into two arrays, and then returns these two arrays. Basically, I have a pool of player objects, and then split them into two teams using very basic team-balancing logic.

When I was writing the reducer logic, I tested it in a separate javascript file and when passing an initial state type object into it I was getting the correct output. (an array of objects)

The idea is that a *separate* component then lists the name property of each player.

When I click the button I get the error in the title and my state is wiped except for the three states I change. MY redux devtool shows both arrays of players just being `[null]`.

#### Button Hook Component

```js
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";

const GenerateTeams = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    function passTeamsIntoState() { //this is the problematic one
        dispatch ({
            type: "GENERATE_TEAMS",
            
        })
    }

    const goToPage = () => dispatch({ //this one changes state fine
        type: "NAV_TO_GENERATE"
    });

    const onClick = () => {
        passTeamsIntoState();
        goToPage();
    }

        return (
            <>
                <button
                    className="doButton"
                    onClick= { onClick }
                >
                    Generate Teams
                </button>
        </>
        )
    }

export default GenerateTeams;
```

The reducer imports a bunch of functions I've put in separate folders, but it returns when I would have thought it should, ...state, then the props we want changed.

#### Reducer logic

```js
import setTeamMembers from './setTeamMembers';
import selectedPlayers from './selectedPlayers';


const GenerateTeams = (state) => {
    let players =  [...state.players];
    let teams_size = state.teams_size;

    // Select required players and generate two balanced teams
    let playerPool = selectedPlayers(teams_size, players);
    return setTeamMembers(playerPool);
}

let teams = GenerateTeams();
console.log(teams);

let team_one = [...teams.team_one_players];
let team_two = [...teams.team_two_players];

let setTeamsReducer = (state) => {
    return {
        ...state,
        team_one_players: team_one,
        team_two_players: team_two,
    }
}

export default setTeamsReducer;
```

The component that is meant to list the players is a Redux class based component:

#### Component that's trying to read the objects

```js
const PlayersCardT1 = ({team_one_players}) => {

    return (
        <ul>
        {
            team_one_players.map(player => (
                <li name = { player.name } key = { player } />
            ))
        }
    </ul>
    )

}

export default PlayersCardT1;
```

and its `index.js` file:

```js
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Players from './PlayersCardT1';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        team_one_players: state.team_one_players,
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Players);
```

Also, Happy new year folks!